# Shared hosting - catch user ip

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I am hosting one site at ccihosting.com and I tried to catch user IP with

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

and I got IP of their server located in panama but not my IP. They told me it is because of shared hosting. But all webhostings have shared servers don't they ? And I got no problems of catching IP addresses. I would like to just know whther it is because of shared hosting or no.

Thanks

Comment: Shared Hosting uses same public IP for multiple domains.

Comment: Everytime you get the panama's IP or just sometimes ?

Comment: everytime the panama ip

Comment: What does the IP address of your server have to do with `REMOTE_ADDR`?

Comment: @Stijn, I was confused too. OP wants the IP address of the CLIENT.

Comment: Well it conffused me as well. Client IP is unique and has nothing to do with the server IP. But however it seems they are ovverriding it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP address of your website differ on **Shared Hosting**. Many websites on Shared Hosting may have different DNS names but same IP addresses.

You will get a *same* IP address only when you are on **Dedicated Hosting Server**.

**EDIT :** Try this alternative code

```
<?php
function get_client_ip() {
    $ipaddress = '';
    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';

    echo $ipaddress;
}

get_client_ip();
?>
```

Comment: but how can it affect the IP of users ?

Comment: He's not talking about an incorrect *server IP* - he's talking about an incorrect **client IP**. Something that would only usually happen if they proxy every request through to their internal network (perhaps it's crappy software load-balancing?)

Comment: @h2ooooooo, Yeah right. Crappy. Found a link here about them.http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=933040

Comment: gonna try it and will inform